# Does hive create separate copy of data

Tags: hadoop, hive

when we create a table in hive using csv file from hdfs then will hive create separate copy of that data?

This will cause unnecessary waste to memory

Comment: Try reading books, tutorials, blog posts, whatever.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter I have followed the link docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.3.0/… Now I can see the copy of data in a bit encrypted form in /user/hive/warehouse folder of HDFS which I set in hive-site.xml .

Answer (score 2):

No, in hive whatever hdfs location you have given at the time of table creation. Data will reside at the same location. There wont be separate copy of data either it is csv or other file formats.

Comment: I have followed the link docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.3.0/… Now I can see the copy of data in a bit encrypted form in /user/hive/warehouse folder of HDFS which I set in hive-site.xml .